# Can I use several "to be continuous" build templates?

Tags: gitlab-ci, to-be-continuous

I have a single Git repository with several independent applications, developed in several languages (a.k.a *monorepo*).

In this repository, can I use multiple [to be continuous](https://to-be-continuous.gitlab.io/doc/) templates to build in parallel all my projects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.

Some build templates also support [parallel matrix jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel-matrix-jobs), allowing you to handle multiple projects using the same template.

### Example

Suppose a GitLab project is made of the following:

- `app/`: a frontend application, developed in Angular
- `users-srv/`: a 1st backend service, developed in Node, packaged as a Docker image
- `orders-srv/`: a 2nd backend service, developed in Node, packaged as a Docker image
- `tools/`: some tooling, developed in Python

Your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file should look like the following:

```yaml
# included templates
include:
  # Angular template
  - project: "to-be-continuous/angular"
    ref: "1.2.0"
    file: "templates/gitlab-ci-angular.yml"
  # Node.js template
  - project: "to-be-continuous/node"
    ref: "1.2.0"
    file: "templates/gitlab-ci-node.yml"
  # Python template
  - project: "to-be-continuous/python"
    ref: "1.2.0"
    file: "templates/gitlab-ci-python.yml"
  # Docker template
  - project: "to-be-continuous/docker"
    ref: "1.2.0"
    file: "templates/gitlab-ci-docker.yml"

# variables
variables:
  # path of the Angular project
  NG_WORKSPACE_DIR: "app"
  # path of the Python project
  PYTHON_PROJECT_DIR: "tools"

# parallel matrix jobs for Node template
.node-base:
  parallel:
    matrix:
    # path of the "users-srv" Node project
    - NODE_PROJECT_DIR: "users-srv"
    # path of the "orders-srv" Node project
    - NODE_PROJECT_DIR: "orders-srv"

# parallel matrix jobs for Docker template
.docker-base:
  parallel:
    matrix:
    # Docker config for project "users-srv"
    - DOCKER_FILE: "users-srv/Dockerfile"
      DOCKER_SNAPSHOT_IMAGE: "$CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/users-srv/snapshot:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
      DOCKER_RELEASE_IMAGE: "$CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/users-srv:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    # Docker config for project "orders-srv"
    - DOCKER_FILE: "orders-srv/Dockerfile"
      DOCKER_SNAPSHOT_IMAGE: "$CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/orders-srv/snapshot:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
      DOCKER_RELEASE_IMAGE: "$CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/orders-srv:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"

# your pipeline stages
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - package-build
  - package-test
  - deploy
  - acceptance
  - publish
  - production
```