Is it possible to define multiple "to be continuous" build templates using CI/CD component?
I know that it is possible to use parallel matrix jobs to handle multiple projects using the same template with the include:project syntax. An example is given here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67884837/15261125
I wonder if it is possible to do the same with the include:component syntax ?

No, unfortunately the include:component syntax doesn't support parallel matrix jobs (yet?).
